# Espera de resultado para proseguir con la creacion de un cliente en API ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, asincronismo

Estoy desarrollando una API en ASP. **NET Core** para la transferencia de datos de un programa de gestión y una plataforma Online.

Uno de los recursos que tengo que exponer, es el de creación de clientes, para este fin el ERP me proporciona una librería para la creación de estos, el procedimiento es simple, yo relleno una tabla de con los datos del cliente y mediante la librería llamo un método que se encarga de dar de alta al cliente.

El problema es que este proceso no es inmediato, ya que este proceso entrara en una cola interna y el ERP lo procesará cuando toque.
Este proceso quedará registrado e identificado con un GUID al que yo podré consultar para conocer su estado.

En el proceso de alta, tengo que crear también una dirección de envío, este proceso si que se hace manualmente insertando los datos en una tabla y vinculando mediante una **foreign Key** al cliente. Por lo que hasta el cliente no esté dado de alta, no puedo conocer su Id para informarlo en la dirección.

En el controlador, definiré un método [POST] asíncrono para la inserción del cliente, eso lo tengo claro, lo que no tengo nada claro es como gestionar la secuencia de creación del cliente-consulta de estado-creación de dirección.
¿Tengo que crear un `while` que vaya consultando el estado de la petición hasta que se haya creado, salir del `while` y crear la dirección? No me parece eficiente para nada y la verdad es que no sé cómo enfocar este tema.

Sé que este tipo de preguntas no son muy bienvenidas por aquí, así que pido disculpas de antemano, solo aclarar que no sabría qué código compartir y que tampoco quiero que me deis la solución, solo me gustaría que me pudierais guiar con que procedimiento es el más eficiente para gestionar este caso.

Muchas gracias y disculpas.

Comment: Para preguntas de este tipo, quizás Meta sea el lugar indicado. Por otro lado, revisa el concepto de webhook; es probable que sea lo que estés necesitando. Por otro lado, esa cola que se genera, debe tener algún mencanismo de avisar los que ya han sido procesados. Saludos

Comment: Gracias, investigo acerca de webhooks. Desconocía Meta mil disculpas.
Lo que se genera es un registro de guid Transaccion/Estado que debe ser consultado. muchisimas gracias.

Comment: Veo que el concepto de webhook se basa en que sea la misma aplicación (en este caso el ERP) el que informe a la API de que el proceso se ha realizado.
Lamentablemente, no tengo esa opción.

Comment: Me parece que es como dices, necesitas un `while` para comprobar el estado obviamente con un `sleep` dentro para no saturar el asunto. Lo otro podría ser con un timer, pero es la misma lógica. La manera eficiente que tu buscas depende directamente de las herramientas que tenga el ERP (y del acceso que tu tengas a ellas), algo como un evento o un trigger, o si esa cola que mencionas es algo como MSMQ o cualquier otro dato que no has entregado en tu pregunta.